# Get All Contracts from Blockchain

Tags: ether, contract-invocation, json-rpc, etherscan, mythril

I am developing a large database of exploitable contract addresses and creating a website to host such a database for users to use to see if contracts are safe.

**Is there a way to get all contract addresses from the ethereum blockchain?**. Currently, I am using a web scraper, but I often get temporarily banned, even when using proxies and fake user credentials.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by querying the blockchain directly instead of using your web scraper. For this, you would need to run a node and check each block's transactions to see if the associated addresses are contracts.

Comment: This sounds like what I am after. I have installed `geth`, but do you have any resources to check a single block for such a contract address?

Comment: There are a few ways. One is to use the `eth_getTransactionReceipt` RPC call that has a `contractAddress` field that is populated if the transaction is sent to a transaction.

Comment: The `eth_getCode` call returns the code at each an address. If the address is a contract, this will return something that is non-zero

Answer (score 1):

By default all full nodes contain every single contract and transaction on the Ethereum network.

I don't know how you would filter only contracts though and there would also be far to many contracts to check them all.

Mabye you could make a system where a user would post about a smart contract instead of reviewing one.

Comment: Do you know if a fast node contains the contract address? I am not looking for the bytecode (which I read a full node contains), but only want the addresses.