# Is there a way to find every contract deployed on chain?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there a way to find every contract erc20 or erc721 or any kind of erc that has been deployed? If so how could I make this? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't mention if using third party tools is ok for you, but in case it is:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139444/obtain-all-smart-contract-addresses-on-ethereum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get All Contracts from Blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74383/get-all-contracts-from-blockchain)

Comment: Hey Elliot thank for your answer but those doesn't really answer to my question sorry

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? The first tells you how to fetch using third party APIs, the second how to do it without. How do you want to do it?

Comment: Do you know tokenfomo website that stream every new ERC20 contract deployed at same time where the deployed deploy it ? i want to make my own script that allow me streaming every contract deployed, for ERC20 and for ERC721 and i can't know how could i do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, usually I use a block explorer such as https://etherscan.io